# How would you set DoubleValue in google protobufs for python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a field of type `DoubleValue` how do I set it with a float in python? Currently, I'm getting an error if I set it with a float:

`Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected DoubleValue got float.`

I've tried this: `DoubleValue(1.23)` but it doesn't work. Not fully understanding this class.

I'm also currently setting it in the python constructor

`ParentClass(value=DoubleValue(1.0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoubleValue` has a property `value`, which you can set in the constructor.

i.e. `DoubleValue(value=1.23)`

Was having the same issue, but found the property hiding in the [documentation.](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/wrappers_pb2.html#google.protobuf.wrappers_pb2.DoubleValue.value)